# Dropzone.js to get file URL

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function which generates the File URL using createobjectURL and works when I use the normal input file tag.

I am trying to implement the same using dropzone.js but when I drop the file it starts
showing the upload progress bar although I haven't defined any action.

How can i obtain the URL using dropzone.js?

### Javascript

```
function localFileVideoPlayerInit(win) {
    var URL = win.URL || win.webkitURL,
        displayMessage = (function displayMessageInit() {
            return function displayMessage() {
                alert("error");
            };
        }()),

        playSelectedFile = function playSelectedFileInit(event) {
            var file = this.files[0];
            var type = file.type;
            var videoNode = document.querySelector('video');
            var canPlay = videoNode.canPlayType(type);
            canPlay = (canPlay === '' ? 'no' : canPlay);
            if (canPlay === 'no') {
                displayMessage();
            }
        }
};

  var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  videoNode.src = fileURL;
},

inputNode = document.querySelector('input');

if (!URL) {
    displayMessage('Your browser is not ' + '<a
             href="http://caniuse.com/bloburls">supported</a>!', true);
    return;
}

    inputNode.addEventListener('change', playSelectedFile, false);
}
```

### HTML

```
<form action="" class="dropzone">
    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Dropzone has a file collection, add a button in the pewview element and add eventlistener on "adddedfile" for this button. Having "file" as an argument on "addedfile" you can use createObjectUrl directly with this argument

Answer (score 0):

Seems you would have to reference the variable `fileURL`, and use javascript to dynamically set the action of the form.

Comment: better never than so late and bs xD

Comment: What does that mean? @TraianTatic